# Looking for advice on how to normalize format of incoming json from different sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, parsing

I am working on a project that receives data (json) from a number of different sources. Each source returns json in a different format, however all services fall into the same category i.e. Issues from Jira and Stories from PivotalTracker each have the same core information.

I am looking for a way to normalize this as much as possible so that I can add other services and formats in the future. Right now I am handling each response type (Jira, PivotalTracker) separately and taking action on each response independently.

So far I am thinking that I'll need a parser for each service, i.e. JiraIssueParser, PivotalTrackerStoryParser etc which transforms the response into a common format that can be used by one method to post onwards, rather than having methods for each to do the receive/parse/post.

Something like this format:

```
{
  issue: {
    title: ,
    description: ,
    assignee: ,
    comments: {
      1: {
        id: ,
        title: ,
        body: 
      }
    time_entries: {
      1: {
        id: ,
        time: ,
        date: 
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would like to define the common schema somewhere so that each parser's output is always identical. I'm thinking this could be done with a YAML file but I'm not sure how to go about it, and how to use that in the parser.

I would greatly appreciate some suggestions on how to do this. Maybe this is a really stupid question and I should just be outputting the above format from each parser, but I think it would make sense to have some kind of format that is enforced/validated.

Suggestions are appreciated and I'm open to taking a new direction with this if anyone has any ideas. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Rails, I assume then that you are going to have a relational database at some point.

What I would suggest is to define ActiveRecord models that express your "normalized" format: Issue, Comment, TimeEntry, etc.

The job of your parsers, then, is to coerce the JSON data into the appropriate model objects and attributes and save them. Your models thus enforce the canonical data structure (i.e. the schema), and you can even use validators to do further sanity checks.

Finally, I would also save the raw JSON somewhere alongside your model, preferably also in the database. Even though you have already parsed the JSON, keeping it around will come in handy for troubleshooting. For example, if you find and fix a parsing bug, you can re-run the parser on the saved JSON without having to re-download everything the original external sources.

Comment: Thanks for your response and good advice. I'm thinking of going with MongoDB for the external objects (Issue, Comment etc). Do you think this would be  good move?

Comment: @Adam I don't have experience with MongoDB, so I can't help you there. I suppose it depends how concrete you expect the canonical schema to be.